# Calculating total distance traveled not accurate

Tags: ios, swift

Using the below code the distance traveled is always lower than the actual distance traveled by 20-40% when traveling at least a couple of miles. This is traveling in a large city with strong cell and GPS signal the entire trip so I know that is not the issue. I verified the actual distance using Google Maps and MapMyHike. Any Ideas?
Relevant parts of the code pasted below:

```
let metersToMiles: Double = 0.000621371
var startLocation: CLLocation!
var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var distanceTraveled: Double = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() // Location permission for background
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // Location permission for foreground

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.Fitness
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if startLocation == nil {
        print("startLocation is null")
        startLocation = locations.first
    } else {
        let lastLocation = locations.last
        let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation!)
        startLocation = lastLocation
        distanceTraveled += distance
    }
    updateDistanceTraveledText()
}

func updateDistanceTraveledText() {
    let distanceTraveledString = "\(String(format:"%.1f", distanceTraveled * metersToMiles))"
    distanceTraveledText.text = distanceTraveledString
}
```

I also tried all types of desiredAccuracy like kCLLocationAccuracyBest and kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters, etc. and not setting activityType at all, and also setting it to AutomotiveNavigation/Fitness all to no avail.

Comment: If you have `always` permission you don't need `whenInUse` permission.  `locations` in `didUpdateLocations` is an array; you may get more than one location update in this method.  You should iterate this array and add any intermediate distances

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible you’re getting a string of location updates as it zeros in on your precise location. Those updates indicate a change in precision, not actual motion — but it looks like your code is going to register them as motion anyway. This can happen no matter how high you set `desiredAccuracy` because [it’s a *maximum* accuracy, not a minimum](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy).

You could debug this by logging the `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties of the `CLLocations` as they come in.

*If* the problem is indeed that you’re getting reports with varying accuracy, some possible solutions are:

- Use the distace filter on `CLLocationManager` to ignore small travel.
- Discard any `CLLocation` that isn’t accurate enough, according to some threshold you set.
- If the latest location falls within the accuracy circle of the previous one (and thus may not represent actual motion), *replace* the last location instead of adding the new one.
- Use some sort of sophisticated Bayesian inference to find the path of maximum likelihood through all reported points.

I’d do #1 or #2 if this is casual, #3 if you really care, and #4 only if maximum accuracy is essential … and you know more about the math than I do.

Comment: I added the horizontal distance filter before, it didn't have any effect

Comment: But did you first do the experiment described in the answer to determine whether this is even your problem? You need to start with better diagnostics.